# How to preserve the column ordering when accessing a multi-index dataframe using `.loc`?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's be given the following dataframe with multi-index columns

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

a = ['i', 'ii']
b = list('abc')
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100,100+len(mi)*3).reshape([-1,len(mi)]), 
                  columns=mi)
print(df)
#     i             ii
#     a    b    c    a    b    c
# 0  100  101  102  103  104  105
# 1  106  107  108  109  110  111
# 2  112  113  114  115  116  117
```

Using `.loc[]` and `pd.IndexSlice` I try to select the columns `'c'` and `'b'`, in that very ordering.

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, idx[:, ['c','b']]]
```

However, if I look at the output, the requested ordering is not respected!

```
#     i        ii
#     b    c    b    c
# 0  101  102  104  105
# 1  107  108  110  111
# 2  113  114  116  117
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why is the ordering not preserved by pandas? I consider this pretty dangerous, because the list `['c', 'b']` implies an ordering from a user point of view.
2. How to access the columns via `loc[]` while preserving the ordering at the same time?

---

**Update: (02.02.2020)**

The issue has been identified as [pandas bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22797). In the process of fixing it, [this related issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31330) has been identified, which addresses a semantic ambiguity for expressions like `df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['c','b']]]`.

In the meantime, the problem can be circumvented using the approach described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from this [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22797):

> I don't think we make guarantees about the order of returned values
>   from a .loc operation so I am inclined to say this is not a bug but
>   let's see what others say

So we should be using `reindex` instead:

```
df.reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,['c','b']]))
     i        ii     
     c    b    c    b
0  102  101  105  104
1  108  107  111  110
2  114  113  117  116
```

Comment: Many thanks! I left a note in the discussion thread you referred to.

Comment: FYI. The problem described in my question has been identified as bug. There is progress in fixing it, but there are some extra hurdles to take. Until this is done, your workaround still applies.